# how to check if a property is some type of Generic.Collections in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, serialization, collections

I need to check if a property is some type of Generic.Collections for the following example I need to check the property Students of TSchool

```
TStudent = class
  private
    FName: string;
  published
    property Name: string read FName write FName;
  end;

  TSchool = class
  private
    FStudents: TList<TStudent>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy;
  published
    property Students: TList<TStudent> read FStudents write FStudents;
  end;


SerializeObject...
  properties := GetProperties(objToSerialize);
  for i := 0 to properties.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if CHECK_IF_IS_COLLECTION(properties[i])
      serializeCollection(properties[i]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean? It seems pretty much self-evident what `Students` is, what with it being clearly defined right there in the code, and known at compile time.

Comment: Also, destructor Destroy needs to be overriden

Comment: I need to check the properties of any object

Comment: Please specify "check the property". Otherwise the answer just is: "Use RTTI".

Comment: I have edited the question, If is a collection I have to do something different

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using RTTI; that's the only context in which your question makes sense.  If that's not correct, let me know and I'll delete or edit this as appropriate.

So you've got a `TRttiInstanceType` that refers to the `TSchool` class, and you extract its properties and find the one called "Students".  Now you have a `TRttiProperty`.  What you want is something like this:

```
function IsGenericCollection(prop: TRttiProperty): boolean;
var
   propType: TRttiType;
   propCls: TClass;
begin
   propType := prop.PropertyType.
   if not (propType is TRttiInstanceType) then
      exit(false);
   propCls := TRttiInstanceType(propType).MetaclassType;
   while propCls <> nil do
   begin
      //or 'System.Generics.Collections', depending on your Delphi version
      if propCls.UnitName = 'Generics.Collections' then
         exit(true);
      propCls := propCls.ClassParent;
   end;
   result := false;
end;
```

This will tell you if a property either is or is descended from a `Generics.Collections` collection.  Feel free to modify it as necessary.

Comment: *This will tell you if a property either is or is descended from a Generics.Collections collection.* Not quite. Just that it is derived from a class, collection or otherwise, declared in that unit. Also I guess the name is System.Generics.Collections now, post XE2.

Comment: @David: As noted in the comment above the line in question. ;)